# There's a way know when a TCP payload ends?

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp

I have a routine that sends data over TCP and must wait a response on the same opened socket.
The data to be receiver doesn't fit in one TCP message, so, the question is This code will wait until the last byte or should I must to add some indication at the end?

```
Private Function SendReport(ByVal Msg As String, ByVal Host As String, ByVal Port As String) As String
       Try
           Dim Tx As New TcpClient()

           Dim stream As NetworkStream = Nothing
           Dim CloseStream As Boolean = False
           Dim LingerMode As New LingerOption(True, 5)

           ' String to store the response ASCII representation.
           Dim responseData As [String] = [String].Empty

           Tx.NoDelay = True
           Tx.LingerState = LingerMode
           Tx.SendTimeout = 10000
           Tx.ReceiveTimeout = 10000
           Tx.Connect(Host, Port)

           ' Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
           Dim data As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Msg)

           ' Get a client stream for reading and writing.
           '  Stream stream = client.GetStream();
           stream = Tx.GetStream()
           CloseStream = True
           'stream.WriteTimeout = 100
           ' Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
           stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)

           'Tx.Connected 
           ' Receive the TcpServer.response.
           ' Buffer to store the response bytes.
           data = New [Byte](256) {}


           ' Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
           Dim bytes As Int32 = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
           responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes)

           If CloseStream = True Then
               stream.Close()
           End If
           Tx.Close()

           Return responseData
       Catch ex As Exception
           WriteRTBLog(ex.Message, Color.Red)
           WriteRTBLog(ex.StackTrace, Color.DarkRed)
           Return "Error"
       End Try

   End Function
```

I never made an application to receive more than one TCP packet before, so I don't know what to expect.
The longer data that I must to expect is about 524KB

Comment: TCP does not have packets or messages at all. It is a stream. You seem to be unaware of this.

Comment: You have the exact same issue even if you're only sending two bytes. TCP doesn't provide any guarantees about how those bytes will be received.

Comment: Ok, so I must to add some indicator at the end to know where is the end. @DavidSchwartz Are you talking about the order? So the 3rd packet can come before the first one?

Comment: @E_Blue You're writing an application. There are no packets at the application layer. Packets are a network thing. At the application layer, TCP is a byte stream.

Comment: You'll need something that indicate the end or something at the beginning that indicate the length of the data. Be carefull, .Read can return just one byte at a time, you'll need to loop until all is read.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand. So I send the data, I must not worry about the order and wait for the end indicator that I added to the data sent .

Comment: @E_Blue Have you ever read the specifications for any protocols that use TCP such as IRC, HTTP, or SMTP? They all cover what a "message" consists of and how you find the end of them.

Comment: No, I never used any protocol, I always use my own.

Comment: Like David said, it's a good idea to read up on a popular protocol. It'll give you a good idea on how to do your own properly. You can read of the RFC for IRC, HTTP, SMTP or even look up the protocol used for a game.

Comment: @the_lotus Thanks for warning me, I was not aware about the .Read can read only one byte. About the protocols, I thought they were closed copyrighted protocols, so the technical specs are not available unless money between.

Comment: @E_Blue I'm not saying it reads only one byte, I mean it [read a unknown number of byte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read(v=vs.110).aspx), could even be 0.

Comment: @the_lotus Yes, I understood that, I was just using your same example.